# Как правильно составить запрос к базе данных postgreSQL с такими параметрами

Tags: sql

Необходимо составить запрос, который найдёт все строки у которых одновременно повторяются поля name и parentid и в этих случаях нужно проставить в конце каждого поля name цифру, начиная с 1 через пробел(Раздел 1, Раздел 2).
Тоесть если у нас 5 строк у которых совпадают name и parentid, то изменить имена начиная с 1, далее к следующим повторам имени и также в конце добавить номер

Должно получиться примерно: "Item 1" - "parent1", "Item 2" -  "parent1", "Item 3" - "parent1";
"Product 1" - "parent 55","Product 2" - "parent 55","Product 3" - "parent 55"

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд в Вашем случае можно использовать оконную функцию ROW_NUMBER() в комбинации с PARTITION BY для определения групп повторяющихся значений:

```
UPDATE ВАША_БД
SET name = name || ' ' || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, parentid ORDER BY name, parentid);
```